# how to include the end date in a filter of java stream

Tags: java

i am streaming a list which has data corresponding to dates and am using this filter filter(s->s.getTime().before(enddate)) to filter the values from the stream between two dates inclusive of the lastdate.

What can I change here so that it includes the endDate? I tried with replacing before with equals but that doesn't help.

Comment: like *not after* that end date?

Comment: What kind of object does `getTime()` return ?

Comment: you can use something like filter(s-> !s.getTime().after(enddate))

Comment: @aman id id what u said but still thats not working out.

Comment: A date in epoch seconds

Comment: @sand87 Whats the datatype of enddate?

Comment: @AmanJ the datatype is Date

Comment: after is a method in date class itself, getTime returns long and thus you must be getting a compilation error : 

You should use it like 

filter(s-> !s.after(enddate))

Comment: Sorry maybe the ques was a bit misleading.i am streaming a list which has data corresponding to dates and am using this filter to filter the values from the stream between two dates inclusive of the lastdate

Comment: @AmanJ yup.i did exactly as is mentioned.Still it somehow doesnt include that end date

Comment: To Simplify things you could just play with long values as: 
filter(s-> (s.getTime()<=enddate.getTime()))

Comment: Set `endDate` time to `23:59:59.999`. Or just do `before(endDate + 1 day at 00:00:00.000)`

Comment: @AmanJ that solution works.

Comment: @sand87 Should i add this as a solution and you can change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `java.util.Date` you could try

```
filter(s-> {return s.before(enddate) || s.equals(enddate);})
```

or simply (thanks to [chai-t-rex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7208029/chai-t-rex))

```
filter(s-> !s.after(enddate));
```

By [my understanding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) this should return `true` for all `s` of type `Date` **before or equal** to `enddate` of type `Date`

Answer (score 1):

To Keep things simple you can just use long values :

```
filter(s-> (s.getTime()<=enddate.getTime()))
```

Since this uses only a single filter, and works with (long) numbers, so you can change the filter as per your liking very easily